# How does Pokemon Radar work?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

After beating the game you can earn something called Pokemon Radar from one of scientist working in prof. Syncamore Labs. This should be used in tall grass and it will do something that will help me find best/strongest pokemon with best stats.

But whenever I'm in tall grass and I wanna use it I heard my in-game Mother voice that it isn't good place.

Where can I use it? Or am I using it passively and I didn't know it?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not using it passively :p.

To use the Pokemon Radar:

- You must be in tall grass. (This includes Flower grass, but unfortunately not the Route 6 grass, caves, or Water).
- You cannot be rollerblading.
- It must be fully charged. (After you use it, you will need to take about 50 steps before you can use it again)

Up to 4 patches of grass will shake. (It technically always chooses 4 spots around you but most patches of grass are smaller than it's range, so it may 'shake' a position that is not tall grass and therefore you will see less than 4.)

If you go into the shaking grass it is very likely that you will fight a pokemon. It is **not** guaranteed though.

After each battle four more spots will shake. If you choose a spot with the same pokemon as the last one you fought the cycle will continue. This is part of a chain.

**Speculation**: It looks like some spots will shake with more intensity than others. The less it shakes the less likely the pokemon in it will be the same as the one you just fought if there is any pokemon at all.

You will end the chain if:

- You start rollerblading.
- You run from battle.
- You encounter a pokemon that is not found in one of the shaking spots.
- You fight a different pokemon than the previous one.
- You do not find a pokemon in the shaking grass at all.

Helpful Tips:

- Repel and abilities like it will help prevent random encounters that may break your chain.
- Supposedly choosing the furthest away piece of grass is your best bet to find the same pokemon.
- You **can** catch any of the pokemon you encounter. It will not break your chain.

http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Radar

Comment: *"Supposedly choosing the furthest away piece of grass is your best bet to find the same pokemon"* - That sounds like another infamous pokemon urban legend...

Comment: Compared to my initial tests where I maybe got 1-3 in a row I made it to 15 by always going to the furthest one. Anecdotal and whatnot but it was pretty telling to see that huge of a difference.

Comment: Sorry but... what mean "I must be fully charged" :) ?

Comment: It is like the Vs. Seeker. Every time you use it you need to recharge it. It is recharged after about 50 steps.